# Issues in Android Studio Terminal

Tags: windows, android-studio, cmd, windows-7, terminal

I am using Android Studio version 1.5 on Windows 7. I also use the terminal inside Android Studio. But if I type anything like e.g. `git checkout 140` and I want to change it to `git checkout feature_140` then I move the cursor per left-key to the place after `git checkout` and type in `feature_`. But then the letters are replaced. So the terminal is in insert mode. How can I change the default behaviour to not replace characters but just extending the typed-in string? The terminal is linked to "cmd.exe". But in Windows "cmd"-terminal the standard behaviour is "not insert". So everything is working fine using Windows Terminal but using Android Studio Terminal causes the described behaviour. What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure? I also use Windows 7 / Studio 1.5. When I move the cursor left and start typing, text gets added and not replaced. Only when I press 'Insert' key, the text is replaced.

Comment: Yes of course. My colleague has the same behaviour as you have(added). But in my terminal I have the replaced-behaviour.